# Laravel Eager Load become null in conditional relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I'm stuck in few days for fixing this problem.

in my case, there is student received a scholar. But student's table and scholar member's table are different. there is deactivated student status date. the student get $70 every month with condition the student still active OR if student status deactivated (drop out / mutation to other school) but the period of month is less than deactivated date.

The problem occurs when the manager wanna see the student that receive scholar with the deactivated student

The model

```
student {
   id, student_number, name, status
}

scholar_student {
  id, student_number, start_registered(date), deactivated(date)  
}
```

Relation :

in Scholar model

```
public function Student() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Student::class,'student_number','student_number')->when($this->status,function($q){
      $q->where('status','active');
   });
}
```

How to get student scholar list in manager :

```
$data = StudentScholar::with('Student')->get();
```

If I'm using `with` the function to add condition `status` always skipped. And if I don't use with it will queried. If I am not using `with` the performance becomes very slow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate methods to fetch active and inactive students.

```
public function ActiveStudent(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Student::class,'student_number','student_number')->when($this->status,function($q){
      $q->where('status','active');
   });
}

public function InactiveStudent(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Student::class,'student_number','student_number')->when($this->status,function($q){
      $q->where('status','inactive');
   });
}
```

When fetching student list

`$data = StudentScholar::with('ActiveStudent','InactiveStudent')->get();`